# How to update a database keeping user data

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database where the user can change a few values in each tuple. I also want to be able to add new rows and update the content of some existing ones. The code I use right now is not good enough, as it creates a new database on the onUpdate()

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("dB update", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MetaData.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to my problem? Or is it possibile at least to avoid updgrading a column, preserving the user values in that column? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite you can use ALTER table to edit it. (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

As you can see in the link you can add and rename columns.

Feel that's all you need

Comment: ALTER TABLE is useful to add columns, but what if I want to add rows and modify some cells values (again, without deleting user data)?

Comment: If you want to rename or delete column names then you'll have to momentarily look through the table, store all its data into an Array of object of the given type, delete the current table and add a new one with the new column names. In a proper implementation you shouldn't need that very often.

If you need to add new rows just use the proper methods insert and update from the class SQLiteDatabase for that goal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll probably use what you suggested or work with more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers and maybe transactions to do this. And also you should look for sql queries.